# npm: is there a package or option to pretend running nightmare on another OS?

Tags: node.js, operating-system, nightmare

Is there a node.js package or a setting/parameter in `nightmare` that allows me to pretend I'm running `npm nightmare` on a different OS like Windows (win32) or MacOS (darwin)?

I notice that if I run `nightmare` to test websites on a Linux/Unix machine, the electron browser behaves differently from running on a Windows machine.

Comment: define "differently" please :D

Comment: In my case nightmare run on Linux/Unix doesn't show the same result from an SQL injection attack on my websites as it does on a Windows machine: a ransom page with fake phone number. I can't give much more details.

Comment: How about you try setting different user agents?